# InMemory DbContext doesnt throw exception when update one-to-many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, dbcontext

I have problem when write tests over Repo that uses DbContext. I set one-to-many relation. I try to create/update InMemory DbContext by new item with non existing fk and this is successfully completes but MUST NOT. Obviously via real Db that code throws exception.

```
class A
{
    public int Id {get;set}
    public int FKB {get;set}
    public B B {get;set;}

}

class B 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<A> Items {get;set;}
}

AConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<A>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<A> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("A").HasKey(a => a.Id);

        builder.HasOne(a => a.b)
                .WithMany(b => b.Items)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.FKB);
    }

}

BConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<B>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<B> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("B").HasKey(b => b.Id);

        builder.HasMany(b => b.Items)
                .WithOne(a => a.B)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.FKB);
    }

}

--- example

var a = new A { id = 1, FKB = 12341};

context.AItems.Add(a);
context.SaveChanges(); // here NO error!?

var bItems = contex.BItems.ToList(); // here empty collection
```

How is it possible and how to fix this?

Comment: Are you adding your custom type configuration in the dbcontext  OnModelCreating?

Comment: @AliK of course

Comment: [This Link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6080) might help